# concatenate in the monero world

Tags: cryptonote

I am trying to replicate in python the  calculation of public key derivation, that is: `P = H(aR||i)G +B` where `i` is the output index in a transaction.

I got all the operators figured out (using a python ed25519 implementation) except for the concatenation.
How is concatenation (`||`) defined in Monero? Is it taking the two scalars as strings and calculate their hash? bitwise `or`? etc...

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`aR` is an elliptic curve point, and has a 32 byte compressed representation. `i` is not a scalar. Scalars, like `a` would have a 32 byte representation. `i` however is a varint. Varints are specified in section 1.2 of this document: https://tukaani.org/xz/xz-file-format.txt

Therefore `aR||i` will usually be 32+1 = 33 bytes of data. The concatenation has no padding, and is simply one byte sequence followed by another.

Also note that although the white paper says `P = H(aR||i)G + B`, if you look at the Monero source code it's actually `P = H(8aR||i)G + B`. This is to avoid small subgroup attacks, because it forces the result of `8aR` to be in the subgroup of the base point G.