# How does concatenation occur in crypto_ops::derivation_to_scalar

Tags: monero-hash

In the function `crypto/crypto.cpp/crypto_ops::derivation_to_scalar`
monero sends the output_index to `tools::write_varint(end, output_index)`.

How does it append the output_index to derivation?

Comment: Kind of related -> https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10420/concatenate-in-the-monero-world/

Comment: In order to repruduce the amount i have tried several calculations similiar to the ones in the answer, however, i didn't get to the right answer so i am assuming the calculation is different.

Comment: `end` is a pointer to the area in the struct to write the varint. That struct (as binary) holds the concatenation. The first 32 bytes are the derivation and the next bytes are the output_index as a varint.

Comment: @adsl if you're unable to reproduce it, you're doing it wrong. I'd recommend you start by attempting to parse existing transactions to see if you can do that successfully.